# how to get the running time from a stanfit object from the saved CSV file

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I have a `stanfit` object saved in csv.

Inside the csv at the end of the file, it is mentioned how much time the model took to run.

Because I have many models, and I would like to see how much was the running time in **total** for **all** the models, i was thinking of using the `read_stan_csv` to read all the csvs and then get the time from each one of them and sum them.

The problem is that I couldn't find the `elapsed time` after reading the csv.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `get_elapsed_time(read_stan_csv(filenames))` is not working for you?

Comment: didnt know about the `get_elapsed_time`. it works. thanks !